# Do I need Federal Employment Agency approval for a Blue Card for year 2020?

Tags: visa, germany

I have a foreign university degree and a job offer with gross pay of €54000. Do I need Federal Employment Agency approval, or can I apply for the visa directly?

Comment: That will be done during the application process. The Consulat will pass the application to the Ausländerbehörde for approval. The Ausländerbehörde will ask the Employment Agency before approving.

Comment: but i tried to book for visa appointment through website it says "Highly Skilled Workers with pre-approval according to § 81 a AufenthG" also it says "Choose this category for only if you have a pre-approval according § 81 a AufenthG ( Residence Act ) in conjunction with the Highly Skilled Immigration Act (Fachkräfteeinwandersungsgesetz)." My employer did not FEA pre approval for me. what should i do now?

Answer (score 0):

It depends not only on one's salary, but also on his/her job and education. See, for example, [notes on this question for Berlin](https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/324659/en/):

> Approval of the German Federal Employment Agency.
>   You need the approval of the Federal Employment Agency if you
>
> - work in a shortage occupation and
> - earn less than EUR 4,600 gross per month and
> - do not have a degree from a German university.